# SQL. Суммирование по колонкам и строкам одновременно

Tags: sql, sqlite

В общем, у меня есть данные по затратам пользователей, где по строкам пользователи, а в колонках месяца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сложить и по строкам и по колонкам, чтобы получить общую сумму. 
Я использую такой запрос: `(SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 1], '$','') as FLOAT))+SUM(CAST(Replace([Колонка 2], '$','')`, 
но при прибавлении третьей колонки выдается NULL. Данные в текстовом виде ($100.00), поэтому я их заменяю на числовой.

В чем может быть проблема при подсчете всей суммы? Подскажите, плиз, правильный запрос.

Comment: Делайте `coalesce(sum(...),0)+coalesce...`

Comment: супер! сработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте для начала создать `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW sum_per_month AS
    SELECT
        , user_id 
        , CAST(Replace([Колонка 1], '$','') as FLOAT) AS [1 month later]
        , CAST(Replace([Колонка 2], '$','') as FLOAT) AS [2 month later]
        , CAST(Replace([Колонка 3], '$','') as FLOAT) AS [3 month later]
        , [1 month later] + [2 month later] + [3 month later] AS id_sum
    FROM source_table;
```

А потом так, делайте запрос к нему:

```
SELECT SUM(id_sum) FROM sum_per_month;
```